# When i destroy my app more than 2 times it does not read in the data from txt file, the data is lost

Tags: android, text-files

I have an app that saves Strings to textfile when closing the app and reads them in again on starting the app. If i destroy my app 1 time the data reappears and if i destroy it a 2nd time it reappears again. However when i destroy it the 3rd time all the data is lost.

I've tried everything but it just dont work, i've tried using onsavedinstancestate() etc but im lost.. If anyone could point me in the right direction i would really appreciate it!

My readFromFile() and writeToFile() methods:

```
private void writeToFile(String data, Context context) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("start.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}

private String readFromFile(Context context) {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("start.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Quite normal that files created through openFileOutput are removed when you uninstall your app if that is what you mean by destroy.

Comment: No with destroy i mean when i close the app not just press the home button.. maybe when app is killed is the right word

Comment: Then that file should never disappear. Is all data lost? But is the file still there but is it empty? Which exception do you get?

Comment: To keep the lines (if there are ) you should change      `stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
` to `stringBuilder.append(receiveString+"\n");
`